# How does split and join work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

But still dont understand : as in input box initially there is no data , however when the user starts typing the functions starts invoking the method in it , however the first line will [ $(this).val().split("-").join("");  ]  will then look for the hyphen character to split into ... but as if the data typed by the user dosent contains any hyphens so what has to be replaced...??? like you explained above e.g. split("-") on "a-b-c" will give ["a","b","c"] ....this data already contains the hyphen character and which gets replaced with the character that we specify in brackets. Again at the other hand i dont understand this too :     foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-"); , why there is single quotes in the RegExp, and what for the 1,4 stands for ..??? as far a i know that it must be meant for minimum 1 and maximum 4 charachters..? could you please help me understanding this..???  Appreciate your help

Comment: split() will split a string into an array based on a given delimiter. join() will join all elements in an array into a string with a given delimiter. The code above simply gets an array of items that match the regex, and then joins them into a single string using a dash as a delimiter

Comment: Learn about regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Simple debugging will show you what happens when there are no hyphens.  `console.log("abc".split("-"))`

Answer (score 5):

The function calls are evaluated from left to right. First `val()`, then `split("-")`and then `join("")`.

What this does, is that it reads the value and since it seems to be a credit card number, the value will be something like `1234-5678-9012-3456`.

The next thing is split the numbers at the hyphens with `split("-")`. This will result in a kind of list `['1234', '5678', '9012', '3456']`.

This list is then joined using `""` (Nothing actually) resulting in `1234567890123456`, the number without the hyphens.

The same thing could be achieved with

`$(this).val().replace(/-/g, "")`

using Regular Expressions.

Hope this clarifies stuff!

Comment: Well if there are multiple `-` than `$(this).val().replace("-", "")` will not work. The string "a-b-c" would be "ab-c". It would need to be `$(this).val().replace(/-/g, "")`

Comment: Yes you're correct. I originally intended to use a RegEx, but I thought it might confuse the author of the questions, since he seems new to programming. Forgot about that limitation. I'll update the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).val()
```

Gets the value of the element:

```
.split("-")
```

Build an array of strings that splits on '-' (hyphen).  Basically, when you find '-' in the string, add it to i.e. 'foo-bar' becomes ['foo', 'bar'].

```
.join("");
```

Take the array and join each element back together with an empty string i.e. ['foo', 'bar'] becomes 'foobar'.

Answer (score 0):

Split and join in one line

```js
const result = "7.83".split('.').reduce((first, second) => `${first}' ${second}"`)

console.log(result)
7' 83"
```